# I want to get the Date and sum of main where main is > 10 for distinct dates(There are many rows for same date) using mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Unnamed: 0  Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  symbol  max_high    main    turnover    emt
52  05-04-1990  57.93229167 57.93229167 55.615  55.615  0   KESARENT    67.20149286 20.83339541 0   0
53  09-04-1990  57.93229167 57.93229167 55.615  55.615  0   KESARENT    67.20149286 20.83339541 0   0
54  10-04-1990  55.615  55.615  55.615  55.615  0   KESARENT    67.20149286 20.83339541 0   0
55  12-04-1990  50.98041667 55.615  50.98041667 55.615  0   KESARENT    67.20149286 20.83339541 0   0
56  19-04-1990  53.2976 53.2976 53.2976 53.2976 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 26.08727758 0   0
57  23-04-1990  54.4563192  54.4563192  51.9073 51.9073 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 29.46443536 0   0
58  25-04-1990  52.13910638 54.4564 52.13910638 54.4564 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 23.40421485 0   0
59  30-04-1990  54.4563192  54.4563192  51.9073 51.9073 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 29.46443536 0   0
60  02-05-1990  53.29770833 55.615  53.29770833 55.615  0   KESARENT    67.20149286 20.83339541 0   0
61  03-05-1990  53.29770833 55.615  53.29770833 55.615  0   KESARENT    67.20149286 20.83339541 0   0
62  04-05-1990  53.29770833 55.615  53.29770833 55.615  0   KESARENT    67.20149286 20.83339541 0   0
63  07-05-1990  50.98045957 54.456
4   50.98045957 54.4564 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 23.40421485 0   0
64  08-05-1990  50.98031304 53.2976 50.98031304 53.2976 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 26.08727758 0   0
65  10-05-1990  50.9804 50.9804 50.9804 50.9804 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 31.81829263 0   0
66  14-05-1990  49.82180667 52.1391 49.82180667 52.1391 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 28.8888624  0   0
67  15-05-1990  48.66310909 50.9804 48.66310909 50.9804 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 31.81829263 0   0
68  17-05-1990  48.66310909 50.9804 48.66310909 50.9804 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 31.81829263 0   0
69  18-05-1990  48.66310909 50.9804 48.66310909 50.9804 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 31.81829263 0   0
70  22-05-1990  48.66315349 49.8218 48.66315349 49.8218 0   KESARENT    67.20149286 34.88371126 0   0
```

i tried doing this with sql but didnt worked. Can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
SELECT 
  `Date`,
  SUM(main)
FROM 
  <your-table>
WHERE 
  main > 10.0
GROUP BY 
  `Date`
```